# Union to return result only if both the queries return result

Tags: sql

```
(select `pk_irfa` 
   from `incident_reports_form_answers`  
  where inc_question_id  = 338 
    AND  answer_text in ("N/A", "Graeme Clark")) 
union 
(select `pk_irfa` 
   from `incident_reports_form_answers`
  where inc_question_id  = 339
    AND  answer_text in ("Manager", "Pass"))
```

I want the query query to work in such a way that if either of the queries return null union should'nt return any records . For example if the question_id 338 returns null then the whole query must return empty data. any suggestions ?

Comment: What do you mean "return null"?  Do you mean no rows?

Comment: yes by null i mean no rows .  i do not want the entire query to return data is either of query returns empty records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need `union`:

```
select pk_irfa
from incident_reports_form_answers
where (inc_question_id = 338 AND answer_text in ('N/A', 'Graeme Clark'))) or
      (inc_question_id = 339 AND answer_text in ('Manager', 'Pass'))
```

Then if you need `pk_irfa`s with both, use aggregation:

```
select pk_irfa
from incident_reports_form_answers
where (inc_question_id = 338 AND answer_text in ('N/A', 'Graeme Clark'))) or
      (inc_question_id = 339 AND answer_text in ('Manager', 'Pass'))
group by pk_irfa
having count(distinct inc_question_id) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this with the help of some CTEs:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT pk_irfa
    FROM incident_reports_form_answers
    WHERE inc_question_id = 338 AND answer_text IN ('N/A', 'Graeme Clark')
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT pk_irfa
    FROM incident_reports_form_answers
    WHERE inc_question_id = 339 AND answer_text IN ('Manager', 'Pass')
)

SELECT pk_irfa FROM cte1 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte2 > 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT pk_irfa FROM cte2 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte1 > 0);
```

Appreciate that each half of the union only returns results if a) its CTE has a result set, *and* b) the other half of the union also has a result set.

Gordon has provided a way of expressing your logic without using a union, but the above is pretty close to the original logic you were using.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as (
  select a1.pk_irfa irfa1, a2.pk_irfa irfa2
  from 
    incident_reports_form_answers a1 
    inner join incident_reports_form_answers a2
    on
      a1.inc_question_id = 338 AND a1.answer_text in ('N/A', 'Graeme Clark') and
      a2.inc_question_id = 339 AND a2.answer_text in ('Manager', 'Pass')
)
select irfa1 as pk_irfa from x
union all
select irfa2 from x
```

If the join fails there will be no rows.. The only question in my mind is whether your conditions uniquely identify a single row in all cases, or whether you'll suffer a cartesian explosion at some point

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts :)

Comment: You can (and should) click the Upvote arrow on any number of answers if you want to say "thanks, this was useful"